# RxSwift - behavior of subscribe(observer:)

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm confused about behavior of subscribe method in RxSwift.
This is sample code.

```
let observer1 = PublishSubject<String>()
let observer2 = PublishSubject<String?>()

let observable1 = Observable.just("")
let observable2 = observable1.map { $0 }

_ = observable1.subscribe(observer1) // #1. OK
_ = observable1.subscribe(observer2) // #2. Error
_ = observable2.subscribe(observer2) // #3. Error
_ = observable1.map{ $0 }.subscribe(observer2) // #4. OK
```

I understand that #2 and #3 get an error.
Because the observer is a nullable-string type, it is strictly different from the type that the observable holds.

But I can not understand #4.
If directly subscribe of the mapped observable, it did not get an error.
As shown in #3, the return value of the mapped observable1 was Observable.

I look forward to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.map { $0 }` actually returns a `Observable<String?>` in the fourth case!

Ww can cast the return value to a `Observable<String>`:

```
_ = (observable1.map{ $0 } as Observable<String>).subscribe(observer2)
```

It stops working! This implies that the value returned by `map` without the cast must be different. And there's only one possibility - `Observable<String?>`. `$0` can't be implicitly convertible to other types.

The compiler sees that you are calling `subscribe(Observable<String?>)` and infers the return type of `map` to be `Observable<String?>` because only then can `subscribe` be called successfully.

But if you don't give the compiler enough context to figure out the type that `map` should return, like you did in the `let observable2 = ...` line, then the compiler thinks you want a `Observable<String>`.

Basically, the compiler is being smart.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I understand clearly.  
Even in the case of using method chaining, the compiler infer properly type.  
The swift compiler is well-made,  isn't it?

Comment: @zico if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Oh... I didn't know the function. Sorry!